# JavaScript promise from jQuery Deferred resolves only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Inside click listener I have a function which return `promise` and open popup window. From popup window I want to pass array of selected values. However this promise works only first time I click "Post" button.

What I am doing wrong?

[Sample](https://dojo.telerik.com/uCoxASAl)

```js
  
  function showtWindow(){
  
    var selected = [];
    var post = false;
    
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    var promise = dfd.promise();
    
   var popupWindow = $("#popupWindow").data('kendoWindow');

    //init window only first time
    if (popupWindow === undefined) {

        popupWindow = $("#popupWindow").kendoWindow({
            title: 'Test',
            width: 400,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                //this.destroy();
                if (post) {
                    dfd.resolve(selected);
                }
            }
        }).data('kendoWindow');

        popupWindow.wrapper.find('.confirm').on('click', function (e) {
            selected = popupWindow.wrapper.find('.list input:checked').map(function (i, el) {
                return $(el).val();
            }).get();

            post = true;
            popupWindow.close();
        });

        popupWindow.wrapper.find('.cancel').on('click', function (e) {
            popupWindow.close();
        });
    }
    
    popupWindow.center().open();

    return promise;
  }
  
  
  
  $('.testButton').on('click', function(){
    var promise = showtWindow();
   
   promise.then(function (e1) {
        console.log(e1)
    })/*.done(function (e2) {
        console.log(e2)
    }).fail(function (e3) {
        console.log(e3)
    })*/
  })
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div hidden="hidden" id="popupWindow">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" />One</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" />Two</label>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button class="confirm">Post</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
  
<button class="testButton">Test</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Post a minimal example of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this was working for me in your KendoSandbox;

```
var popupWindow, dfd;
function showtWindow(){

    var selected = [];
    var post = false;

    dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    var promise = dfd.promise();

    popupWindow = $("#popupWindow").data('kendoWindow');

    //init window only first time

    if (popupWindow === undefined) { // removed the if undefined clause

    popupWindow = $("#popupWindow").kendoWindow({
        title: 'Test',
        width: 400,
        height: 600,
        modal: true,
        close: function () {

            if (post) {
                dfd.resolve(selected);
            }
            // this.destroy();
        }
    }).data('kendoWindow');

    popupWindow.wrapper.find('.confirm').on('click', function (e) {
        selected = popupWindow.wrapper.find('.list input:checked').map(function (i, el) {
            return $(el).val();
        }).get();

        post = true;
        popupWindow.close();
    });

    popupWindow.wrapper.find('.cancel').on('click', function (e) {
        popupWindow.close();
    });
    } // removed the if undefined clause

    popupWindow.center().open();

    return promise;
}
```

Hope this helps, I am just overwriting popup & associated promise, on click of the button, such that the promise (thrown) can be captured with every button click.

Comment: If I open popup multiple times, then multiple event listeners will be added for 'Post' and 'Cancel' buttons.

Comment: That is why you define the popupWindow variable at the top so that it overwrites the existing popup.

Comment: Could you re-arrange my code, because I don't quite get it. Moving variable to global scope causes duplicates for me.

Comment: Everything here is because of the scope of the defined function `popupWindow` if we define it as global it retains the events associated with this, please read [ https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope ] it will be clearer